# Non-boundary nodes in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

I have a binary tree, i want to print all non-boundary nodes.
Boundary Nodes:- All leaf nodes+all nodes on path from root to leftest node+all nodes from root to rightest node.

I ave done this using an extra boolean in tree structure to identify whether it's boundary node or not and then doing a traversal and printing if not boundary nodes. Can someone come up with a better approach, because it's using some extra space(though very less).

Comment: "leftest" should be "leftmost." "rightest" should be "rightmost."

Answer (score 4):

One observation you might find helpful is that a non-boundary node in a binary tree is one that (a) isn't a leaf and (b) is one where along the access path to the node, you've taken a step left and a step right. Therefore, one option would be to do a normal tree traversal, tracking whether you've gone left and gone right along the way. Here's some pseudocode:

```
function printNonBoundaryNodesRec(root, goneLeft, goneRight) {
    if (root == null or root is a leaf) return;

    if (goneLeft and goneRight) print root.value
    printNonBoundaryNodesRec(root.left, true, goneRight);
    printNonBoundaryNodesRec(root.right, goneLeft, true);
}

function printNonBoundaryNodes(root) {
    printNonBoundaryNodesRec(root, false, false);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: And if you are somewhere in the middle?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri My apologies, but I don't understand what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: He wants to print non boundary nodes. Boundary is all nodes that are surraunding tree. Like a triangle.